# How to set variable arguments default to empty in C?

Tags: c

I have a macro like this.

```
#define TRACE(fmt, ...) trace(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);
```

But sometimes I don't want to supply format string.
Something like TRACE() should do. 
Right now, I use

```
TRACE("%s", "")
```

Is there any way to simplify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about?

```
#define TRACE(...) trace(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)


TRACE("");
```

The `...` ellipsis has to replace at least one argument, so if you use the form `TRACE(fmt, ...)` you cannot use a single argument when calling `TRACE`.

For this reason the form `TRACE(...)` is usually preferred over the form `TRACE(fmt, ...)`.

Also note that I removed the `;` in your macro definition. It's a bad practice to have it in the definition, the `;` has to be put after the macro call instead. See this CERT document if you want more information: [PRE11-C. Do not conclude macro definitions with a semicolon](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE11-C.+Do+not+conclude+macro+definitions+with+a+semicolon)

Comment: don't put a `;` in a macro.

Comment: @JensGustedt indeed, I copy/paste and didn't notice the `;`, I'm adding an edit.

Comment: and also just to mention that, my answer is better :)

Answer (score 1):

Adjacent string literals are merged into one single string. So the following should work

```
#define TRACE(...) trace(__FILE__, __func__, "" __VA_ARGS__)


TRACE();
TRACE("hello");
TRACE("integer %d", 42);
```

will result in something equivalent to

```
trace(__FILE__, __func__, "");
trace(__FILE__, __func__, "hello");
trace(__FILE__, __func__, "integer %d", 42);
```

The only restriction that this has is that the first argument, if any, must really be a string literal. Another `char*` object wouldn't work.

(Observe the use of `__func__` this one is the predefined identifier for the function name as of the C standard. And the lack of the `;` in the macro to better fit into the usual function call convention in the flow of normal C code.)

Comment: `TRACE();` actually violates `C99, 6.10.3p4` constraint: you need at least one argument in your macro call.

Comment: @ouah, I do not see where you read that from. For macros, other than for functions, this is not a lack of an argument but an empty argument. For example there is explicit provision in the standard how an empty macro argument strigyfies, namely as `""`. So the paragraph that you cite is prefectly satisfied, there is 1 argument to the macro call.

Comment: `C99, 6.10.3p12` (not a constraint btw) may be more appropriate here. But to be fair after reading it again I'm now not 100% sure `TRACE();` call is invalid. My point was an empty argument is not one argument but zero argument, but I agree I can be totally wrong here. I would appreciate if other SO users could comment.

Comment: Talking in freenode about this, someone made the point that in the C99 Rationale they use the wording *A function-like macro invocation f() has the form of either a call with no arguments or a call
with one empty argument.* I think this goes indeed in favor of `TRACE();` being valid.

Comment: @ouah, just look at a macro calls `toto()` `toto(,)` and `toto(,,)`. They have 1, 2, and 3 empty arguments, all of which is permitted during the preprocessing phases.

Comment: +1, sorry for my own confusion and upvote for the good answer